# How to create an array from the data attribute of multiple elements in JS ES6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dataset

I'm trying to create an array from data attributes of multiple elements, in proper JS ES6.

Let's use the following HTML:

```
<div class="item" data-geo="['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4]">
<div class="item" data-geo="['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5]">
<div class="item" data-geo="['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3]">
<div class="item" data-geo="['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2]">
<div class="item" data-geo="['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]">
```

I want to grab the data attribute ('data-geo', JSON format) from each element and turn it into an array in JS, like so:

```
  var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1],
  ];
```

Found a lot of examples in jQuery so far but none in JS ES6.

Comment: I think you didn't find any ES6 example because ES6 has not much to see with DOM manipulation. ES6 is like a refactoring of a few methods of javascript particularly arrow function and array methods.

Answer (score 3):

Using [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset)

```js
var locations = []

document.querySelectorAll('[data-geo]').forEach(el =>
    locations.push(JSON.parse(el.dataset.geo.replace(/'/g, '"')))
)

console.log(locations)
```

```html
<div class="item" data-geo="['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4]">
<div class="item" data-geo="['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5]">
<div class="item" data-geo="['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3]">
<div class="item" data-geo="['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2]">
<div class="item" data-geo="['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]">
```

Comment: Nice one @user862 :)